# Check if row value in each column is in previous rows of the same columns (returning customers) with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a dataframe with customer names that are sorted on arrival date like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4'],
                  data = [
['John Doe', 'Michael Miller', 'Elizabeth Wilson',  'Jennifer Williams'],
['Joe Bloggs', 'Jessica Davis', 'Alex Anderson', 'Olivia Martinez'], 
['Jane Smith', 'Emily Brown', 'Nicholas Robinson', None],
['Emily Brown', 'Sophia Clark', None, None ],
['Sarah Johnson', 'Daniel Garcia', 'Mia Taylor', 'William Davis'], 
['Michael Miller', None, None, None], 
['Nena Robins', 'Nicholas Robinson' ,'Grace Miller', None]
])
```

I want to check if a customer is a returning customer or not. For this purpose I want to look in a row and see if the customer name was in a previous row (Note that the customer can appear in each of the columns' previous rows).

I expect to get:

```
            Name1              Name2              Name3              Name4     RC
0        John Doe     Michael Miller   Elizabeth Wilson  Jennifer Williams  False
1      Joe Bloggs      Jessica Davis      Alex Anderson    Olivia Martinez  False
2      Jane Smith        Emily Brown  Nicholas Robinson                NaN  False
3     Emily Brown       Sophia Clark                NaN                NaN   True
4   Sarah Johnson      Daniel Garcia         Mia Taylor      William Davis  False
5  Michael Miller                NaN                NaN                NaN   True
6     Nena Robins  Nicholas Robinson       Grace Miller                NaN   True
```

Emily Brown is also in row 3
Michael Miller is also in row 1
Nicholas Robinson is also in Row 3

I tried using `~df['Name1'].duplicated()`, but this only checks whether the value has appeared in the same column, not in each Name column.

Comment: your input is unclear, please provide a DataFrame constructor or at least a clear representation that separates the columns

Comment: I have priovided a constructor, hope this makes it more clear. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), run [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) and [`groupby.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.any.html):

```
df['RC'] = df.stack().duplicated().groupby(level=0).any()
```

Output:

```
            Name1              Name2              Name3              Name4     RC
0        John Doe     Michael Miller   Elizabeth Wilson  Jennifer Williams  False
1      Joe Bloggs      Jessica Davis      Alex Anderson    Olivia Martinez  False
2      Jane Smith        Emily Brown  Nicholas Robinson                NaN  False
3     Emily Brown       Sophia Clark                NaN                NaN   True
4   Sarah Johnson      Daniel Garcia         Mia Taylor      William Davis  False
5  Michael Miller                NaN                NaN                NaN   True
6     Nena Robins  Nicholas Robinson       Grace Miller                NaN   True
```